# Feynman-Kac-Formula on Riemannian manifolds with Diffusion tensor and drift vector

Tags: stochastic-processes, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a bit of an exotic partial differential equation:

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian Manifold, $D^{\mu \nu}$ a positive definite symmetric 2-tensor and $\mathfrak{F_{\mu}}$ a covariant tensor on $M.$

We consider the partial differential equation

$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = \nabla_{\mu} D^{\mu \nu}(\nabla_{\nu}-\mathfrak{F}_{\nu})n.$$

I would now like to derive its Ito process and also solve the equation with the Feynman-Kac formula.

Can anyone help me? I was looking for literature, but all the generalizations for manifolds only did standard Brownian motion without a vector field as a drift. So I was wondering if somebody might have a reference.

Thanks in advance!